# Bukkit plugin not working

Tags: java, bukkit

So I was trying to have a go at creating a plugin for minecraft. The first version worked fine, it only had /heal and /h now i've added /day and /weed and it doesn't work anymore. When I type /pl in-game it doesn't show "kBase"

Plugin class:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    System.out.println("kBase has been enabled");
}



@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal") || cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if (player.hasPermission("kbase.heal")) {
                if(args.length == 0){
                    ((Damageable) sender).setHealth(20);
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been healed!");
                } else if(args.length == 1){
                    String playerName = args[0];

                    Player selected = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(playerName);

                    if (selected == null) {

                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "The player" + ChatColor.GOLD + playerName + ChatColor.RED + "Is not online");

                    } else {

                        selected.setHealth(20.0);
                        selected.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been healed");
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You have healed" + ChatColor.GOLD + playerName);

                    }

                }
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have enough permissions");

            }
        }else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                if (sender instanceof Player) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    World world = player.getWorld();
                    if (player.hasPermission("kbase.day")) {
                        world.setTime(0);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "LET THERE BE LIGHT!");
                    } else {
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have enough permissions");
                    }
                }else if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weed")) {
                    if (sender instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        if (player.hasPermission("kbase.weed")) {
                            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS, 40, 1));
                            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 100, 1));
                        } else {
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have enough permissions");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

There are no errors at all in this class

plugins.yml:

```
name: kBase
main: pw.klassic.kbase.kBase
version: 1.0

commands:
    heal:
        description: Heals yourself or someone else
    h:
        description: Heals yourself or someone else
    day:
        description: Makes the time day
    weed:
        description: Smoke weed everyday

permissions:
    kbase.heal:
        default: op
    kbase.day:
        default: op
    kbase.weed
        default: op
```

Console log:

http://pastebin.com/aD3qExLb

~ Klassic

Comment: Are you getting an exception in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `plugin.yml` file, the line `kbase.weed` doesn't have a `:` at the end.